# is it possible to setup pixelsearch priority?

Tags: autohotkey

hello im newbie to this macro program. it is perfectly working fine, i wanted to loop clicking green button pixels until its gone to screen, however everytime there's 2 or more or another green pixel appeared. it clicks it even it is not successfully clicking the first pixel it sees until it disappear and and going nuts clicking any new green pixel it sees and appear.. could anyone suggest any idea how to achieve it?

heres the animated gif image
http://i.imgur.com/f9TdXAa.gifv

```
Loop {
PixelSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, 0x00FF00, 0, fast
        if(ErrorLevel=0) {
                MouseClick, left, %X%, %Y%
            sleep, 300



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... could anyone suggest any idea how to achieve it?

I've got an idea! How about after detecting your Green dot at x,y location you run a different routine/loop with the same pixel search command but instead of using the entire screen maybe calculate a narrow field around your object... than  when the object is no longer present, return to the main loop that searches the entire screen to find another object!

NOT TESTED! but should be something like this:

```
MainLoop() {
Loop {
    PixelSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, 0x00FF00, 0, fast
        if(ErrorLevel=0) {
                MouseClick, left, %X%, %Y%
            sleep, 300
            RefinedLoop(x, y)
}

RefinedLoop(pX, pY) {
    Loop {
         pX := X + 50
         pY := y + 50
         dX := X - 50
         dY := Y - 50
         PixelSearch, X, Y, %pX%, %pY%, %dX%, %dY%, 0x00FF00, 0, fast
            if(ErrorLevel=0) {
                MouseClick, left, %X%, %Y%
                sleep, 300
            }
            Else if (ErrorLevel <> 0)
                i++
            If (i > 10)
                MainLoop()
    }
}
```